Airship flutter notification taps not working when the app is closed. (iOS)
My flutter application receives notifications using Urban Airship. I want these notifications to take the user to a custom page depending on the notification type. This currently works as it is meant to apart from when the app is completely closed. For example if I tap a notification when the app hasn't been closed from swiping it up in the background then it will just open the app without running the code inside my
Airship.push.onNotificationResponse.listen((event){}

To test this I cloned the flutter airship git repo
https://github.com/urbanairship/airship-flutter
and the only change I made is to animate to page 1 when a notification is clicked
Airship.push.onNotificationResponse.listen((event) {
    debugPrint('Notification Response $event');
    controller.animateTo(1);
});

this is only working when the app isn't closed (I am running my app in release mode and then closing it and then tapping a notification I am sending myself using postman to test this functionality)
again this functionality works when the program is open or in the background but not closed.
here is the code in the main.dart
import 'package:airship_example/screens/message_center.dart';
import 'package:airship_example/screens/message_view.dart';
import 'package:airship_example/screens/preference_center.dart';
import 'package:airship_example/screens/settings.dart';
import 'package:airship_example/screens/test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Notification;
import 'package:airship_example/styles.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show DeviceOrientation, SystemChrome;

import 'package:airship_example/screens/home.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:airship_flutter/airship_flutter.dart';

// Supported deep links
const String home_deep_link = "home";
const String message_center_deep_link = "message_center";
const String settings_deep_link = "settings";

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> backgroundMessageHandler(PushReceivedEvent event) async {
  debugPrint("Background Push Received $event");
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  var config = AirshipConfig(
    androidConfig: AndroidConfig(
        notificationConfig: AndroidNotificationConfig(
      icon: "ic_notification",
    )),
    defaultEnvironment: ConfigEnvironment(
        appKey: KEY,
        appSecret: SECRET,
        logLevel: LogLevel.verbose,
        ios: IOSEnvironment(logPrivacyLevel: AirshipLogPrivacyLevel.public)),
  );

  Airship.takeOff(config);
  Airship.push.android
      .setBackgroundPushReceivedHandler(backgroundMessageHandler);

  Airship.push.iOS.setForegroundPresentationOptions([
    IOSForegroundPresentationOption.banner,
    IOSForegroundPresentationOption.list
  ]);
  Airship.contact.identify(USERID);

  Airship.messageCenter.setAutoLaunchDefaultMessageCenter(false);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

// SingleTickerProviderStateMixin is used for animation
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller;

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    initPlatformState();
    addFlutterTag();
    trackFeatureFlagInteraction();

    // Uncomment to enable Hybrid Composition on Android
    // InboxMessageView.hybridComposition = true;
  }

  static void trackFeatureFlagInteraction() {
    Airship.featureFlagManager.flag("rad_flag").then((flag) {
      Airship.featureFlagManager.trackInteraction(flag);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint('Error: $e');
    });
  }

  static void addFlutterTag() {
    Airship.channel.addTags(["flutter"]);
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    Airship.push.onPushReceived.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Push Received $event');
    });

    Airship.push.onNotificationResponse.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Notification Response $event');
      controller.animateTo(1);
    });

    Airship.push.onPushTokenReceived.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Push token received $event');
    });

    Airship.push.onNotificationStatusChanged.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Notification status changed $event');
    });

    Airship.push.iOS.onAuthorizedSettingsChanged.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Authorized settings changed $event');
    });

    Airship.push.iOS.authorizedNotificationSettings
        .then((value) => debugPrint("authorizedNotificationSettings $value"));
    Airship.push.iOS.authorizedNotificationStatus
        .then((value) => debugPrint("authorizedNotificationStatus $value"));

    Airship.onDeepLink.listen((event) {
      const home_tab = 0;
      const message_tab = 1;
      const settings_tab = 2;

      switch (event.deepLink) {
        case home_deep_link:
          {
            controller.animateTo(home_tab);
            break;
          }
        case message_center_deep_link:
          {
            controller.animateTo(message_tab);
            break;
          }
        case settings_deep_link:
          {
            controller.animateTo(settings_tab);
            break;
          }
      }
    });

    Airship.inApp.onEmbeddedInfoUpdated
        .listen((event) => debugPrint('Embedded info updated $event'));

    Airship.messageCenter.onInboxUpdated
        .listen((event) => debugPrint('Inbox updated $event'));

    Airship.messageCenter.onDisplay
        .listen((event) => debugPrint('Show inbox $event'));

    Airship.messageCenter.onDisplay.listen((event) {
      key.currentState
          ?.push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return event.messageId != null
            ? MessageView(
                messageId: event.messageId ?? "",
              )
            : SizedBox();
      }));
    });

    Airship.channel.onChannelCreated.listen((event) {
      debugPrint('Channel created $event');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: key,
      title: "Airship Sample App ",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Styles.borders,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          secondary: Styles.airshipBlue, // Set the accent color to airshipBlue
        ),
        switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
          trackColor:
              WidgetStateProperty.all(Styles.airshipBlue), // Set track color
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => tabBarView(),
      },
    );
  }

  Widget bottomNavigationBar() {
    return Container(
      color: Styles.borders, // Set the same color as the tab bar
      child: SafeArea(
        bottom: true,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            color: Styles.borders,
            child: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Styles.airshipRed,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey, // Set unselected label color
              labelColor:
                  Styles.airshipBlue, // Set selected label color to airshipBlue
              tabs: const <Tab>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.inbox),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                ),
              ],
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tabBarView() {
    return PopScope(
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      onPopInvoked: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Styles.borders,
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Home(),
            MessageCenter(),
            PreferenceCenter(),
            Settings()
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The full code can be found on the git repo https://github.com/urbanairship/airship-flutter

In the line
For example if I tap a notification when the app hasn't been closed from swiping it up in the background then it will just open the app without running the code inside.
I meant to say that the function is not run when the notification is tapped from a terminated state but is run when the notification is tapped from a foreground or background state.
